# How to update nested fields on insert conflict with Gorm?

Tags: database, go, struct, grails-orm, upsert

I've got two models, Dictionary and DictionaryRecord with a foreign key on Dictionary.

```golang
type DictionaryRecord struct {
    Id           string `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Name         string
    DictionaryId string
}

type Dictionary struct {
    Id      string `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Name string 
    Records []DictionaryRecord
}
```

I'd like to make sure that when creating a dictionary with a nested record changed, to have the change reflected during the upsert.

```golang
package main

import (

    // Sqlite driver based on GGO
    "gorm.io/driver/sqlite"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "gorm.io/gorm/clause"
)

func main() {
    db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("gorm.db"), &gorm.Config{})

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    db.AutoMigrate(
        &DictionaryRecord{},
        &Dictionary{},
    )

    db.Clauses(clause.OnConflict{
        Columns:   []clause.Column{{Name: "id"}},
        DoUpdates: clause.AssignmentColumns([]string{"name"}),
    }).Create(&Dictionary{
        Name: "AAAAA",
        Id:   "e831ab86-db60-4a71-ba63-f20a181cd69b",
        Records: []DictionaryRecord{
            {
                Id:           "66f73e9b-61b8-4bc9-941d-80d7fd80f8f4",
                Name:         "will be updated",
            },
        },
    })

}
```

How do you specify that the column name in the `DictionaryRecord` must be updated?

Answer (score 2):

can you try use pointer

```
type DictionaryRecord struct {
    Id           string `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Name         string
    DictionaryId string
}

type Dictionary struct {
    Id      string `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Name string 
    Records []*DictionaryRecord //on this records
}
```